# Cannot get audiences to work with LdapRoleProvider

Tags: 2007, audience-targeting, ldap

I have a publishing SharePoint site set up that allows self-provisioning accounts.  I'm using ADMembershipProvider, along with the LdapRoleProvider. When user's create an account, they are automatically added to a default AD group, which is already added to the built in Visitors SharePoint group. So once the user creates an account and logs in, he/she has access to the landing page.

We have some web parts that we set up to display only to certain user's in AD groups.  With this, we chose to use audiences.  After entering the AD group in the audience for the web part, it does not display even if the current user is assigned to that AD group.  I found a blog post that explains exactly what is happening, but even after trying his suggestion, it still is not working.

[LdapRoleProvider and Audience Targeting Bug](http://rrfreeman.blogspot.com/2009/08/ldaproleprovider-and-audience-bug.html)

Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer (or workaround) to this that you can add below?

Comment: I went a different route with what I was trying to accomplish. Audiences weren't going to work for me, since I needed the change to happen immediately after the user clicked the button to hide/display a webpart. I later learned about personalization in SharePoint, and this solved what I was trying to do.

Comment: @shannon.stewart: Could you post this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a different route with what I was trying to accomplish. Audiences weren't going to work for me, since I needed the change to happen immediately after the user clicked the button to hide/display a webpart. I later learned about personalization in SharePoint, and this solved what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a users' group in sharepoint? or the user group comes from AD?

Have you try to setup an audience rule?

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/sortinganditerating/article.php/c13255__2/